# Which software can scan image to text?

Tags: images, scanning

I'm looking for a software that scans an image, and then replaces all the text in that image with text that you can edit, such as copy it, add to it, etc. Preferably, the one that can scan the most languages. In windows 10 or 7

Comment: Which OS" which price range? What did you find sofar (google for e.g. "scan image to text" or "ocr" or "optical character recognition").

Comment: Ya akhi all these scan image to text softwares are free as I have seen. And what I found so far was a software that does scan image to text, but by putting the text on another side.